# Checking whether the number of unique numbers within array exceeds n

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just as title reads, I need to check whether the number of unique entries within array exceeds *n*.

`Array.prototype.some()` seems to fit perfectly here, as it will stop cycling through the array right at the moment, positive answer is found, so, **please, do not suggest the methods that filter out non-unique records and measure the length of resulting dataset** as performance matters here.

So far, I use the following code, to check if there's more than `n=2` unique numbers:

```js
const res = [1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,4,1].some((e,_,s,n=2) => s.indexOf(e) != s.lastIndexOf(e) ? false : n-- ? false : true);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%}
```

And it returns `false` while there's, obviously 3 unique numbers (2,3,4).

Your help to figure out what's my (stupid) mistake here is much appreciated.

***p.s.*** I'm looking for a pure JS solution

Comment: You've got an O(n^2) algorithm, if you're worried about performance.

Comment: @Pointy : now it seems to be O(n) to me. Nonetheless, no luck still.

Comment: Well you completely changed the code; now the `.sort()` makes it O(n log(n)).  You have to make a complete pass over the array to determine what you're looking for. The simplest way to do it would be to keep a mapping of values to repeat counts, and then after looking at the entire array just check to see if there are at least `n` entries with repeat count 1.

Comment: Filtering out duplicates in a performant way (e.g. using a Set then using .size, or reducing to an object then listing its keys) would probably be at least as efficient as a manual lookup / count. That being said, your code fails because you reset m to 2 for every call of `some`, so it never reaches 0. Use an external variable or set it on the `thisArg`

Comment: Time complexity can't get better than `O(n)` because every number in the array must be visited to find the number of unique numbers.

Comment: Any solution involving sorting wouldn't give better time complexity than `O(n log(n))`. We can achieve a better `O(n)` time complexity using map as mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030926/2924577).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if a value is unique or duplicate, the whole array needs to be scanned at least once (Well, on a very large array there could be a test to see how many elements there is left to scan, but the overhead for this kind of test will make it slower)

This version uses two [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
function uniqueLimit(data,limit) {
  let
    dup = new Set(),
    unique = new Set(),
    value = null;
  for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
    value = data[i];
    if ( dup.has(value) ) continue;
    if ( unique.has(value) ) {
      dup.add(value);
      unique.delete(value);
      continue;
    }
    unique.add(value);
  }
  return unique.size > limit;
}
```

I also tried this version, using arrays:

```
function uniqueLimit(data, limit) {
  let unique=[], dup = [];
  for (let idx = 0, len = data.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
    const value = data[idx];
    if ( dup.indexOf(value) >= 0 ) continue;
    const pos = unique.indexOf(value); // get position of value
    if ( pos >= 0 ) {
      unique.splice(pos,1); // remove value
      dup.push(value);
      continue;
    }
    unique.push(value);
  }
  return unique.length > limit;
};
```

I tested several of the solutions in this thread, and you can find the result [here](https://jsperf.com/find-unique-numbers-in-array). If there are only a few unique values, the method by using arrays is the fastest, but if there are many unique values it quickly becomes the slowest, and on large arrays slowest by several magnitudes.

**More profiling**

I did some more tests with node v12.10.0. The results are normalized after the fastest method for each test.

**Worst case scenario**: 1000000 entries, all unique:

```
Set     1.00     // See this answer
Map     1.26     // See answer by Nikhil
Reduce  1.44     // See answer by Bali Balo
Array   Infinity // See this answer
```

**Best case scenario**: 1000000 entries, all the same:

```
Array   1.00
Set     1.16
Map     2.60
Reduce  3.43
```

**Question test case**: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1]

```
Array    1.00
Map      1.29
Set      1.47
Reduce   4.25
```

**Another test case**:  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5 ]

```
Array    1.00
Set      1.13
Map      2.24
Reduce   2.39
```

**Conclusion**

The method that uses Set works for both small and large arrays, and performs well regardless of if there are many unique values or not. The version that are using arrays can be faster if there are few unique values, but quickly becomes very slow if there are many unique values.

Comment: The task is slightly different - I need to count only entries that appear exactly once, not all of them.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Sorry I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer, and also checked the other solutions. I have created a test at jsperf to see which solution was the fastest.

Comment: Your answer (`Set` version) indeed provides the fastest solution among those that pass all my test cases. So, I accept that one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with array values as map keys and count as values. Then iterate over map values to find the count of unique numbers. If count exceeds the limit return `true`, if not return `false`.

Time complexity is `O(n)`. It can't get better than `O(n)` because every number in the array must be visited to find the count of unique numbers.

```js
var data = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1];

function exceedsUniqueLimit(limit) {
  var map = new Map();

  for (let value of data) {
    const count = map.get(value);
    if (count) {
      map.set(value, count + 1);
    } else {
      map.set(value, 1);
    }
  }

  var uniqueNumbers = 0;

  for (let count of map.values()) {
    if (count === 1) {
      uniqueNumbers++;
    }

    if (uniqueNumbers > limit) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(exceedsUniqueLimit(2));
```

Comment: You can make it a little bit faster if you instead of `if (map.has(value))` first try to get the value `let count=map.get(value);` and then test if you got it `if (count)` (it will be undefined if not found, and at lest 1 or above if found), and then change `map.set(value, map.get(value) + 1);` to `map.set(value, count + 1);` [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/find-unique-numbers-in-array)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @some. I edited my answer. That's a little performance gain by not making `map.has(value)` call.

Answer (score 1):

Using sets, We count hypothetical unique set size and duplicateSet size and delete unique set element for each duplicate found. If unique set size goes below n, we stop iterating.

```js
function uniqueGtN(res, n) {
  let uniqSet = new Set(res);
  let max = uniqSet.size;
  if (max <= n) return false;
  let dupSet = new Set();
  return !res.some(e => {
    if (dupSet.has(e)) {
      if (uniqSet.has(e)) {
        uniqSet.delete(e);
        console.log(...uniqSet);
        return (--max <= n);
      }
    } else {
      dupSet.add(e);
    }
  });
}
console.log(uniqueGtN([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1], 2));
```

Comment: [fails](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/pozqYmG) when the number of unique elements is equal (*does not exceed*) to threshold and when the threshold is 0.

Comment: @Yevgen Sorry about that,  Edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a type of problem like this, I always like to peek at how the [underscore JS](https://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) folks have done it.

[Ed again: removed _.countBy as it isn't relevant to the answer]

Use the `_.uniq` function to return a list of unique values in the array:

```
var u = _.uniq([1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5]); // [1,2,3,4,5]
if (u.length > n) { ...};
```

[ed:] Here's how we might use that implementation to write our own, opposite function that returns only *non-unique* collection items

```js
function nonUnique(array) {
  var result = [];
  var seen = [];
  for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (seen.indexOf(value) === -1) { // warning! naive assumption
      seen.push(value);
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  console.log("non-unique result", result);
  return result;
};

function hasMoreThanNUnique(array, threshold) {
  var uArr = nonUnique(array);
  var accum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var val = array[i];
    if (uArr.indexOf(val) === -1) {
      accum++;
    }
    if (accum > threshold) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var testArrA = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // unique values: [3, 4, 5]
var testArrB = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4]; // [4]
var testResultsA = hasMoreThanNUnique(testArrA, 3)
console.log("testArrA and results", testResultsA);

var testResultsB = hasMoreThanNUnique(testArrB, 3);
console.log("testArrB and results", testResultsB);
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. My bad, I didn't mention that I'm seeking for pure JS solution.

Comment: Any solution involving sorting wouldn't give better time complexity than `O(n log(n))`. We can achieve a better `O(n)` time complexity using map as mentioned in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030926/2924577).

Comment: "Any solution involving sorting..." - I omitted the code branches that invoke a more efficient algorithm when `array` is sorted

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - I figured, which is why I posted the actual source of the underscore functions for you :) It does look like I may have missed extraction of some methods like `getLength` - I will fix that with naive replacements

Comment: @JoshE - But you can't assume an array is sorted to begin with. Of course, there will be efficient implementations if you are dealing with a sorted array.

Comment: It looks pretty verbose already (you may check out [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031173/11299053) I've progressed to for comparison) does it worth that in terms of performance?

Comment: I've updated to add the snippet and to correct some logical defects I introduced in my adaptation of the original code

Comment: @JoshE You do `if (accum >= threshold) return true;`, but the question was for "exceeds n", so you should change it to `if (accum > threshold) return true;` Also note that `nonUnique` returns an array of every duplicate value. So if there was 324 number 1 in the input, it returns an array with 324 elements with 1. That will hurt performance in your second loop. [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/find-unique-numbers-in-array)

Comment: thanks for the `accum > threshold` - fixed. Regarding the second loop, as long as `threshold <<< nonUnique.length`, the second loop will bail out after a relatively few number of iterations. Good point about that, notwithstanding

Answer (score 0):

From your original solution, I have changed few things, it seems to be working fine:

```js
(function() {
  const array = [1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,4,1];
  
  function hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, number) {
    return array.some((e,_,s,n=number) => {
      let firstIndex = s.indexOf(e);
      let lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf(e);

      // NOT unique 
      if (firstIndex != lastIndex) {
        return false;
      }

      // unique
      return e > n;
    });
  }

  console.log('1', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 1));
  console.log('2', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 2));
  console.log('3', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 3));
  console.log('4', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 4));
 })();
```

So the shorter version looks like this:

```js
(function() {
  const array = [1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,4,1];

  function hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, number) {
    return array.some((e,_,s,n=number) => s.indexOf(e) != s.lastIndexOf(e) ? false : e > n);
  }

  console.log('1', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 1));
  console.log('2', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 2));
  console.log('3', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 3));
  console.log('4', hasExceedingUniqueNumber(array, 4));
 })();
```

Comment: [fails](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/wvwRbgB) when the number of unique elements does not exceed the threshold

Comment: You are totally right, let me take a look and correct that!

Answer (score 0):

The code listed in your question does not work because m is not shared across the calls to the some callback function. It is a parameter, and its value is 2 at each iteration.

To fix this, either put m outside, or use the `thisArg` of the `some` function (but that means you can't use an arrow function)

```
let m = 2;
const res = [1,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,4,1,1]
    .sort((a,b) => a-b)
    .some((n,i,s) => i > 0 && n == s[i-1] ? !(m--) : false);

// ----- or -----

const res = [1,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,4,1,1]
    .sort((a,b) => a-b)
    .some(function(n,i,s) { return i > 0 && n == s[i-1] ? !(this.m--) : false; }, { m: 2 });
```

Note: this code seems to count if the number of **duplicates** exceeds a certain value, not the number of unique values.

---

As another side note, I know you mentioned you did not want to use a duplicate removal algorithm, but performant ones (for example hash-based) would result in something close to O(n).
Here is a solution to count all the values appearing exactly once in the initial array. It is a bit obfuscated and hard to read, but you seem to be wanting something concise. It is the most performant I can think of, using 2 objects to store values seen at least once and the ones seen multiple times:

```
let res = [1,1,2,3,4].reduce((l, e) => (l[+!l[1][e]][e] = true, l), [{},{}]).map(o => Object.keys(o).length).reduce((more,once) => once-more) > 2;
```

Here is the less minified version for people who don't like the short version:

```
let array = [1,1,2,3,4];
let counts = array.reduce((counts, element) => {
    if (!counts.atLeastOne[element]) {
        counts.atLeastOne[element] = true;
    } else {
        counts.moreThanOne[element] = true;
    }
    return counts;
}, { atLeastOne: {}, moreThanOne: {} });
let exactlyOnceCount = Object.keys(counts.atLeastOne).length - Object.keys(counts.moreThanOne).length;
let isOverLimit = exactlyOnceCount > 2;
```

Comment: With your first method (which is modified version of not very good of mine). Here m seems to be incremented upon finding duplicate, which leads in a totally wrong direction. `Set` method will give you the number of all unique entries (**including repeating ones**) which is not what's needed. If I'm missing something, could you, please, post a live snippet to see above code in action?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - Yes, I misunderstood your question, sorry, I think your question could benefit from a little detailed explanation at the top. You want the number of values that appear exactly once in your array, right ? I will update.

Comment: resetting `m` upon each iteration was a nice catch that helped me to progress. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I updated the second part of my answer. Did I understand correctly what you needed ? The number of values that appear once in the array ?

Comment: (Note: you could get rid of the last reduce and just store the 2 values and do the difference manually on the next line, I just wanted to keep it a one-liner without extra variables)

Comment: I created a [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/find-unique-numbers-in-array) to test different solutions. I'm sorry to inform you that this solution wasn't the fastest.

Comment: @some fair enough, as mentioned it was the most performant I could _think of_. Of course if you need to run the method more than 500k times per second, you would need to improve it, but in this case thinking of a different data structure to not have to solve this problem is probably the best solution. I would also encourage you to be careful with JSFiddle as you tend to improve performance only in the scenario covered by the test. e.g. your "v4" is very performant for small arrays but becomes extremely slow on bigger ones (100k+ elements). https://jsperf.com/find-unique-numbers-in-array/5

Comment: I meant JSPerf* not JSFiddle

Comment: @BaliBalo You are correct that the version with arrays quickly becomes a nightmare. I did some testing with different data, but not as large as 100k arrays. I did more testing, with 1M entries, both worst case scenario (all unique) and best case scenario (all the same). You can see the results in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I came up with the following:

```js
const countNum = [1,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,4,1,1].reduce((r,n) => (r[n]=(r[n]||0)+1, r), {});
const res = Object.entries(countNum).some(([n,q]) => q == 1 ? !(m--) : false, m=2);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

But I don't really like array->object->array conversion about that. Is there a faster and (at the same time compact) solution?

Comment: This version of reduce is slow on big arrays because you create a new object for each iteration of reduce, and copy all the keys of the previous object to the new one. (exponentially slower as the number of unique values increase). Try to modify the accumulator `r` and return it itself. `(r,n)=>(r[n]=~~r[n]+1,r)`

Comment: @BaliBalo : is that better now?

Comment: your misgivings about the array->object->array conversion I think are for good reasons. To avoid the object allocation you're performing you'd need to maintain an array of "seen" elements (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031067/105566), even if that doesn't fit with your thoughts on being "compact"

Comment: @JoshE : wouldn't you mind to post working live snippet for cost-benefit analysis?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - Any reason for avoiding a simple and efficient solution involving map: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030926/2924577?

Comment: @Nikhil : for something to start with, it does not provide expected output - returns `false` whereas the number of unique elements (2,3,4) exceeds 2.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov - Fixed it. It is working as expected now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030926/2924577.

Comment: You are doing same thing as I'm doing but with an object instead of map, and using `reduce()` instead of `for` loop for iterating. Also, `Object.entries()` can be replaced with `Object.values()`. Using `some()` for this doesn't seem semantically correct because usually the condition used in `some()`'s callback isn't expected to change while iterating over the array. You could do the same with a `for` loop and break when the condition is reached.

Comment: Personally, using non-descriptive variable names and packing complex operations in one line does nothing to improve performance and usually hurts readability. As of now, your code fails if `m` is negative. Now try handling that in the ternary operator without it getting still messy.

Comment: @Nikhil: Negative array elements are beyond my use case. *'...does nothing to improve performance'* and still, it [may](https://jsperf.com/bweroiasdf/1) perform faster in best case scenario. 'Readability' is a vague concept, some people find it easier to decipher one-liners, based on high order methods, others prefer to deal with multiline `for` loops. I'm not stating here that my method is more efficient than yours, it's just different. However, thanks for your suggestions.